# What is the expected value of this question?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

There is a lottery system with 12 kinds of cards. Everyday I'm allowed to take one card from the system and the odds of taking each kind of cards is equal(1/12).The number of each kind of cards is unlimited. Once I collect all 12 kinds of cards I'll get a reward. So the question is how many days are expected to take to collect all kinds of cards?

Which tool should I use to solve this question?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Can probability say the exact days to collect 12 cards

Comment: @NamburuKarthik I may not describe the question well. The question is to compute the expected value / average days to collect the set of cards.

Comment: @Théophile That's exactly what I need, Thanks!